# Set only two flexboxes in one row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been trying this for a long time but nothing seems to be working. 
I have some `divs` that I am generating dynamically. Now I want each row to contain only `two divs`, so I read that I should use `flex css` property. But I am not getting it right. Currently all the divs are coming in a single row.
Here is my code

```css
.flexbox
{
    display: flex;
}

 

.flexbox > div
{
   flex: 1 1 50%;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 20px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) to make flex items break to multiple lines, and also `box-sizing: border-box` to keep padding inside width of element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexbox > div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: in this case if there are odd number of div the last one spans the entire row. Can I have it cover only 50% of the row

Comment: Yes you can use `flex: 0 0 50%` instead.

Comment: Works awesome thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use width:50%:

```
div{
float:left
display:inline-block;
width:50%;
}
```